# What about expenses on unused resources in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure

The main question is: do I have to pay for unused resources? For instance, Azure pricing calculator says approximately $30/month for XS box. This includes about 750 hours. What if I don't use them all? This is normal for early stage, while development is in progress.

This is just to make it clear if its cheaper to have a virtual hosting for development and beta-testing purposes.

Comment: This is a question that you will have to ask the support of the product you are using. Stack Overflow is a programming related Q&A site.

Comment: Well, you're probably right. I know that this is kinda stupid question, because MS states that I have to pay for deployment, but then I just don't understand why they talk about "computations". When nobody send requests to my App there are no computations.

Comment: Compute Instance is equivalent to a VM. Just like renting a hotel room: you pay whether you're in it or not. You're renting space on the rack, load balancers, fabric controller, etc. You pay whether at 0% CPU or 100% CPU, because you've reserved data center resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly a programming question.

That said: Windows Azure Compute instances are metered by the hour, and metering happens when you have deployed instances (whether running or stopped). If you're doing dev work, deploy for an hour or two (or how long it takes you to test), then delete the deployment. Very easy to delete, very easy to redeploy. Just don't delete the actual hosted service definition (urlname.cloudapp.net, associated certificates, affinity group, etc.). Following this pattern, it's easy to test with 5-10 concurrent instances in a deployment throughout the month - just remember to delete the deployment after each test cycle.

@Bart is partially right about SQL Azure being billed for the month. It's actually amortized daily. This also means: If you set up a 5GB db and only have 99MB on a given day (or days), you're billed at the $4.999 monthly rate / # of days in month). That's about 17 cents daily if you stay under 100MB. And if you delete the db, you're no longer billed.

Same goes for Cache - the cost is amortized daily.

I'd look at the full pricing page [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/).

Comment: Interesting. That thing about SQL Azure is also an important part but i forgot to mention it in my question. I would really like to allocate some max space i.e. 5G, but pay for it only when it goes up to some level - 100Mb, 1Gb, 2Gb...

Comment: Generally, I see that my understanding was nearly the same. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to pay for unused resources in SOME of the services.

In your example, if you deploy a website for 10 hours you will be billed for the 10 hours of usage.  PLUS any transactions/bandwidth associated with it.

However, some the services do have a flat fee.  For example, if you deploy a 5 gig DB to SQL Azure and u do not use it...u will be billed the monthly rate even if it just sits there.

Also your definition of "use it" needs to be clear.  Azure will bill you, if you have ANYTHING deployed.  Even if the VM is stopped, you are getting billed.  Therefore, the best solution is to:
- monitor your usage (its updated multiple times per day)
- use a free trial, MSDN account or promotion to see what the charges will be
- call MIcrosoft...Azure is the hot thing now and they WILL give you a break on charges if they are within reason.